# Linq query to exclude matching strings from c# list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# list full of strings.

I would like to exclude those items that match a specific pattern like those strings that start with "DST*"

Any string that doesn't start with DST, am happy to take, but anything that starts with DST I would like to remove from this list.

I see linq has `Contains()`. But how do I do the inverse of `Contains()`?

Comment: Where is your code, did you try anything?

Comment: I have used this approach 
filtered = listOfStrings.Where(x => !x.StartsWith("DST")); and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> anything that starts with DST I would like to remove from this list.

You don't need LINQ  you could also use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0):

```
listOfStrings.RemoveAll(s => s.StartsWith("DST"));
```

But of course this modifies the original list and does not create a new. If that's desired use the approach from [Somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259677/284240).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `!` operator to inverse any bool:

```
var filtered = listOfStrings.Where(x => !x.StartsWith("DST"));
```

Comment: You forgot `.ToList()` at the end, I think :)

Comment: @IvanKhorin Depends what OP wants to do with the result.